# mod_rewrite redirect for site that contains drupal

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to using mod_rewrite, so I need an explanation in simple terms. I'm trying to do a redirect for a directory that is in the same directory as a Drupal installation but is not part of Drupal.

For example, a file used to exist at http://mysite.com/events/listen/song.mp3. I rearranged so that the file now resides at http://mysite.com/listen/song.mp3.

I can use the following in mod_rewrite and it works:

```
RewriteRule ^events/listen/(.+)$ listen/$1 [NC]
```

However, I'd like to do a real redirect, so that the user sees the new URL instead of the old one. I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^events/listen/(.+)$ listen/$1 [R,NC]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^events/listen/(.+)$ http://mysite.com/listen/$1 [R,NC]
```

Neither of these work. I think it probably has to do with all the rerouting that Drupal is doing, though I do have my rewrite rules before Drupal's in .htaccess. Is there something obvious I'm missing? Or is there a way to allow this to work without messing up what Drupal is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^events/listen/(.+)$ listen/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you please explain why R=301 will work when R by itself will not? And what does L do? Thanks!